# How to send link with data flash message in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter, I want to send link with data flash message in codeiniter how can I send the link? 
this is my session message.

```
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div id="message" class="alert alert-error">Your account is not active yet. Please activate your account.</div>');
```

I want to send link like that

```
  <a href="<?php site_url().'/home/link';?></a>
```

how can I send, please help me to to this thanks in advance

Comment: let me know r u getting any errors if you append the link along with the message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller create a link and assign it in a variable like this

```
function index(){
    $link = site_url('home/link');
    //Now assign this variable in flash and redirect
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div id="message" class="alert alert-   error">Your account is not active yet. Please activate your account.</div>');    
    $this->session->set_flashdata('link', $link);    
    redirect('othercontroller/method');
}
```